# How to pick a directory for packeges installation?

Tags: package-management, software-installation

I have a limited space under a '/' directory and I want to packages installed with `apt install` and similar were placed under specified directoey (ex. `/mount/Dune/Data`). Is there any way I can achieve that? And similar question for selecting a directory for fetching packages.

Comment: It's not a wise idea to do this. Can you give more information about your storage predicament?  Where were you thinking you would be able to install software?  How much free space is on your device and how is that free space allocated in terms of drives/partitions?

Comment: I have 2 disks. The system usues '/' path and everything that is included in this directory. On that disk I have 130GB total. The other disk is on `/mount/Dune/Data` path and there's 1TB data.

Comment: *"130GB"* This is an *ocean* of free space for Linux software. What did you believe would use it all up?

Comment: 130GB for Linux alone is enough. But it shrinks when adding more and more packages (some text editor, some library and so on). And yes, this answers perfectly. Love you, Nmath! <3

Comment: My entire desktop install, including system, all packages, all personal data, and several movies, fits in 30GB.

Comment: I have 3 desktops installed on my system and thus my desktop system is very bloated! (loads of extra software too) and I semi-regularly have to fight with a full / system, however my partition is 27GB.